# Group by with summarise in date difference in R

Tags: r, group-by, date-difference

I am trying to use group_by and then summarise using date difference calculation. I am not sure if its a runtime error or something wrong in what I am doing. Sometimes when I run the code I get the output as days and other times as seconds. I am not sure what is causing this change. I am not changing dataset or codes. The dataset I am using is huge (2,304,433 rows and 40 columns). Both the times, the output value (digits) are the same but only the name changes (days to secs). I would like to see the output in days. 
This is the code that I am using:

```
data %>% 
group_by(PRODUCT,PERSON_ID) %>% 
summarise(Freq = n(),
          Revenue = max(TOTAL_AMT + 0.000001/QUANTITY), 
          No_Days = (max(ORDER_DT) - min(ORDER_DT) + 1)/n())
```

This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2OL2.png).

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Depending on how different two datetimes are, the units used for output printing may change, e.g. `Sys.time() - (Sys.time() + 3)` vs `Sys.time() - (Sys.time() + 1e6)` , which would make me think that your data and code have not been exactly the same each time.

Comment: data was the same, but I ran entire data processing codes in chunks sometimes and line by line other times. Does this make any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but I'm thinking you may have missed a line accidentally from one run to the next. It may well be a bug or combination of factors causing something to happen, but without a small example which shows it giving different results there's really no way to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `difftime()` You might need to specify the units.

```
set.seed(314)
data <- data.frame(PRODUCT = sample(1:10, size = 10000, replace = TRUE),
                   PERSON_ID = sample(1:10, size = 10000, replace = TRUE),
                   ORDER_DT = as.POSIXct(as.Date('2019/01/01') + sample(-300:+300, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)))


require(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(PRODUCT,PERSON_ID) %>% 
  summarise(Freq = n(),
            start = min(ORDER_DT), 
            end = max(ORDER_DT)) %>%
  mutate(No_Days = (as.double(difftime(end, start, units = "days"), units = "days")+1)/Freq)
```

gives:

```
PRODUCT PERSON_ID  Freq start               end                 No_Days
<int>     <int> <int> <dttm>              <dttm>                <dbl>
1       1         1   109 2018-03-21 01:00:00 2019-10-27 02:00:00    5.38
2       1         2   117 2018-03-23 01:00:00 2019-10-26 02:00:00    4.98
3       1         3   106 2018-03-19 01:00:00 2019-10-28 01:00:00    5.56
4       1         4   109 2018-03-07 01:00:00 2019-10-26 02:00:00    5.50
5       1         5    95 2018-03-07 01:00:00 2019-10-16 02:00:00    6.2 
6       1         6    79 2018-03-09 01:00:00 2019-10-04 02:00:00    7.28
7       1         7    83 2018-03-09 01:00:00 2019-10-28 01:00:00    7.22
8       1         8   114 2018-03-09 01:00:00 2019-10-16 02:00:00    5.15
9       1         9   100 2018-03-09 01:00:00 2019-10-13 02:00:00    5.84
10      1        10    91 2018-03-11 01:00:00 2019-10-26 02:00:00    6.54
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score -1):

Why is the value devided by **n()**?

Simple `as.integer(max(ORDER_DT) - min(ORDER_DT))` should work, but if it doesn't then please be more specific and update me with more information.

Also while working with datetime values it's good to know ***lubridate*** library

Comment: dividing by n() is part of the business logic here. `as.integer()` just convert that field to an integer field. I was trying to keep that field as part of diff date.